# Group By clause in cassandra db using Spring java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, query-builder

I want to query in my cassandra db with Group By clause

```
select = QueryBuilder.select().from("USER_TABLE");
     
select.where(QueryBuilder.eq("MOBILE_NO",
            "999999**99")); group_BY(ROLLno);
```

Can any one pls explain me group by here,how to query in java spring boot for cassandra

Comment: Is `ROLLno` a partition key?  Cassandra only supports `GROUP BY` on partition key, or partition key + clustering key(s).

Comment: Seeing this code it seems MOBILE_NO is the parition key.

You need to make ROLLno clustering key to make this code work.

Comment: okay got it,thanks ,can any one of you  send me the syntax or reference where can i see group by in cassandra,bcz i want to implement in spring boot,and yes mobile No is partition key @tarun

Comment: you can go through the link https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html and dont forget to upvote the answer.